# Excel VBA Split function to work in a range

Tags: excel, vba

[UDPATED]
I try to automate my solution to divide one cell into several others in one row, but still have some issues to divide the data from one cell as below:
The final version need to divide range of data in column E starting from E2 (E2:E)

[image]

Ok, after some modifications:

```
    Sub g()


    Dim strInput As String, strOutput As String
    Dim stringValue As String
    Dim LastRowcheck As Long
    Dim n1 As Long
    Dim i As Long
  
    LastRowcheck = Sheets("T4").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("T4").Activate
    
    For n1 = 2 To LastRowcheck
    With Worksheets("T4").Cells(n1, 1)
    stringValue = Sheets("T4").Cells(n1, 5).value
       
    Sheets("T4").Cells(7, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "price", "price2")
    Sheets("T4").Cells(8, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "price2", "status")
    Sheets("T4").Cells(9, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "status", "min")
    Sheets("T4").Cells(10, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "min", "opt")
    Sheets("T4").Cells(11, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "opt", "category")
    Sheets("T4").Cells(12, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "category", "code z")
    Sheets("T4").Cells(13, n1 + 4) = getPart(stringValue, "code z", "", True)
    End With
    Next n1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub

Function getPart(value As String, fromKey As String, toKey As String, Optional isLast As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long
    
    pos1 = InStr(1, value, fromKey & ":")
    
    If (isLast) Then
        pos2 = Len(value)
    Else
        pos2 = InStr(pos1, value, toKey & ":") ' HERE DEBUGGER STOPS
    End If
    
    getPart = Trim$(Mid$(value, pos1, pos2 - pos1))
End Function
```

Comment: `May I use

stringValue = Sheets("T4").Range("5,i") as a proper assignment?` That's incorrect. Type "range vs cells vba" in Google. There are lot of links which explain how to use `Range()` and `Cells()`

Comment: Correct your code `stringValue = Sheets("T4").Range("5,i")` to `stringValue = Sheets("T4").cell(n1 , 5).value` and good to go

Comment: You've a typo on cells(n1, 5) there Kin Siang.

Comment: Ok, I updated the first post in the topic, still getpart function is making me some troubles.

Comment: Having "code z" as a keyword breaks the pattern - are you sure the keyword there is not just "z" (as implied by your image)?

Comment: yes, there is an issue 'code z:' is a keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test frame works for all strings of the form where the keyword is a text string either without spaces or with a space-single-character ending. `SpecialSpread` illustrates a way to use this to take a single cell and spread the split values over the cells to the right.

```
Function SpecialSplit(Compound As String) As Variant
Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long
Dim firstSplit As Variant
Dim elmts As Integer
Dim elmt As Integer
Dim oneel As String

firstSplit = Split(Compound, ":")
For elmt = LBound(firstSplit) To UBound(firstSplit) - 1
    oneel = firstSplit(elmt + 1)
    pos1 = InStr(oneel, " ")
    pos2 = Len(oneel)
    While pos1 > 0 And pos1 < Len(oneel) - 1
        pos2 = pos1
        pos1 = InStr(pos2 + 1, oneel, " ")
    Wend
    firstSplit(elmt) = firstSplit(elmt) & ":" & Left(oneel, pos2 - 1)
    firstSplit(elmt + 1) = Right(oneel, Len(oneel) - pos2)
Next elmt
    
elmts = UBound(firstSplit) - LBound(firstSplit) ' one shorter
If elmts > 0 Then ReDim Preserve firstSplit(1 To elmts)

SpecialSplit = firstSplit

End Function

Sub SpecialSpread(FromCell As Range)
Dim splitSet As Variant
splitSet = SpecialSplit(FromCell(1).Text)
If UBound(splitSet) >= 0 Then
    FromCell(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(splitSet) - LBound(splitSet) + 1).value = splitSet
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank yu a lot for your answer. I try to figure out how to exchange: a = SpecialSplit("asdf:asdf asds:ert ert qwe d:sdfg") into  a = SpecialSplit("???") where ??? is cell address in active workbook, sheet 'T4'

Comment: I want use data from cell E2 in sheet T4 instead of ("asdf:asdf asds:ert ert qwe d:sdfg"). I still have some troubles. Sub qtest()
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant
'a = SpecialSplit("asdf:asdf asds:ert ert qwe d:sdfg")
SpecialSplit = Sheets("T4").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1).value = a
End Sub

Comment: @stasser I revised the example subroutine to be more useful for your case, and to ignore blank input.